# Usage of froze for computer

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, american-english

> - My computer is freezing
> - My computer froze
> - My computer has frozen

which one of these is correct?  The intention is to indicate that the computer is hung/immobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - My computer froze.
> - My computer has frozen.

Either of these is very commonly used for this sense, and is perfectly valid and natural.

> My computer is freezing.

This is less common, and might be thought odd, unless it describes a repeated event: "*My computer keeps freezing when I ...*"

However in casual speech with no forethought, it might be used and would probably be understood.